# Spring-Hibernate insertion Error with Exception

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, hibernate-mapping

I am developing a small Spring and hibernate base application in java, and my appication has a **one to many relationship with Employee and Unit**, Employee has a one unit, Unit has a many Employee. 
in this small application genarate error like this `

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException:
>   Column 'unit_id' cannot be null

**if allow to null value to unit_id other data inserted with out insert unit_id**

here my Entity class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)

    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "epf")
    private int epf;

    @Column(name = "fname")
    private String fname;

    @Column(name = "lname")
    private String lname;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @JoinColumn(name = "unit_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne//(optional = false)
    private Unit unit;


@Entity
@Table(name = "unit")
public class Unit implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name")
```

My controller Class

```
@RequestMapping(value="/employee.do", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView doActions(@ModelAttribute Employee emp, BindingResult result, @RequestParam String action, Map<String, Object> map){
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("employee");

        Employee employeetResult = new Employee();
        switch(action.toLowerCase()){   //only in Java7 can put String in switch
        case "add":
            employeeService.addEmployee(emp);
            employeetResult = emp;
            break;
        case "edit":
            employeeService.updateEmployee(emp);
            employeetResult = emp;
            break;
        case "delete":
            employeeService.deleteEmployee(emp.getId());
            employeetResult = new Employee();
            break;
        case "search":
            Employee searchedStudent = employeeService.getEmployee(emp.getId());
            employeetResult = searchedStudent!=null ? searchedStudent : new Employee();
            break;
        }
        map.put("employee", employeetResult);
        map.put("employeeList", employeeService.getAllEmployee());
        return modelAndView;
    }
```

My DAO Class

```
> @Repository public class EmployeeDaoImp implements EmployeeDao {
> 
>   @Autowired  private SessionFactory sessionfactory;
>           public void addEmployee(Employee emp) {         sessionfactory.getCurrentSession().save(emp);
> 
>   }
> 
>       public void updateEmployee(Employee emp) {
>       sessionfactory.getCurrentSession().update(emp);
> 
>   }
> 
>       public void deleteEmployee(int id) {
>               sessionfactory.getCurrentSession().delete(getEmployee(id));     }
> 
>    Employee   public Employee getEmployee(int empId) {
>               return (Employee) sessionfactory.getCurrentSession().get(Employee.class,empId);     }
> 
>       public List getAllEmployee() {
>               return sessionfactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Employee").list();  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `@JoinColumn(name = "unit_id", referencedColumnName = "id")` you are defining a FK on the Unit table which can not be null. You need to link your employee to some unit using `employee.setUnit(someUnit)` in your code before saving it to the DB.

Comment: dear sir, where i need to link employee to unit object?

inside the Controller or DAO ?

Comment: Unless I'm missing your point, when you are creating an employee, you should assign it to an existing unit.

Comment: How assign it, i don 't know how fix it... can you explain please

Comment: Well, like I said, basically before saving it, you should do something like employee.setUnit(someUnit)

Comment: I got the point, but where i shout put it.... inside the dao, controller or  service..

Answer (score 0):

column id should not be null.you will get better answer from the [guruzon.com](http://guruzon.com). They have included detail explanation with sample codes and programs.other than [hibernate](http://guruzon.com/5/hibernate) they have explained Hadoop Technology with sample programs,Sping,Interview questions